# Dreamweaver, gallery

Tags: html, image, gallery, hyperlink, dreamweaver

Can anyone help me, am new to dreamweaver, trying to do an online portfolio and am struggling to figure out how to do a gallery.

Basically I want to have a basic list (contents page) of my projects on the left of my spread and when clicked onto a specific project, images for that project appear on the right of the spread. I need to link text to images within the same page

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This isn't really what SO is for: there are plenty of good tutorials out there that you should read to get you started, here's one - http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/dreamweaver/photo_album.htm

Comment: @Karl Barker, I think the tutorial you have suggested might be a bit dated. As far as I am aware of the photo album feature has been removed from CS5. I assume Andrea you are using CS5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, you can create beautifull galleries using jQuery.

Here is an example of a plugin for creating one:
[Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/)

It's easy to use, just read the documentation